# Emacs/xterm color annoyance on Linux

Tags: linux, emacs, terminal, colors, xterm

I'm using emacs in a console window both on my local Linux box and on the login node of a remote cluster.  I use emacs regularly, and I've got the foreground color set to white in my .emacs file like so:

```
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-background-color "black")
```

However, when I run emacs, the foreground isn't white; it's grey and very hard to read.  On my Mac, emacs in a console window with the same settings shows up as proper white.  But on both linux boxes, in konsole and xterm, it's grey.

In case it matters, I've got `TERM` set to xterm-color, the desktop is running RHEL 5, and the cluster node is running RHEL 4 (CentOS).

Is this some default with how Linux sets up terminal colors?  How do I get white to be white?

**Note:** this is with console emacs, not emacs under X.  That's `emacs -nw` if you have `DISPLAY` set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The color `brightwhite` looks ok on my Emacs (which is running under a terminal, not X).  On RHEL5 I have my `TERM` environment variable set to `xterm-256color`.  If it's working correctly, you should be able to run [these scripts](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) and see 256-color output.  Under Emacs, you should see a reasonably smooth color ramp (no obviously duplicated colors) when you do `M-x list-colors-display`.  If not, you are probably missing the right termcap entry (try installing the `libtermcap-devel` package, I think).

If I change `TERM` to `xterm-color`, then `brightwhite` comes out a bit gray in the output of `list-colors-display`.

I'm not sure about RHEL4.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
(set-foreground-color "brightwhite")
```

In response to comment:

Within emacs, run `M-x list-colors-display` which should show you all of the colors that emacs thinks are available with your terminal.

Comment: Does this work for you?  I tried it, but it gives me black menus and status bars, and the text is shown as the default foreground color from my terminal (which is green).  Maybe I don't have "brightwhite"

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiments, and you can set console colors in emacs, but you are limited to this palette:

```
black                    blue                                         
cyan                     green                                        
magenta                  red                                          
white                    yellow
```

The white that you get is somewhat grayed out; full bright white is reserved for bold text.  So if you run

```
M-x facemenu-set-bold
```

you will get bold (bright white) text for later insertions.

I had no luck trying to force the default face to bold.
(I don't really understand how faces work in emacs.)

Comment: "but you are limited to this palette" - This is not really true, emacs supports 256 colors assuming your terminal is properly setup.  See screenshot @ http://seanbright.com/e256.png

Comment: @Sean: pick up some reputation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684424/how-do-i-set-up-my-linux-x-terminal-so-that-emacs-has-access-to-256-colors

Answer (score 2):

What if you just used reverse-video for the console version is that good enough?

```
$ emacs -nw -rv
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're only setting the foreground color.

```
(set-foreground-color "white")
(set-foreground-color "black")
```

I'm sure you meant `set-background-color` on the latter.

I can confirm this when running Emacs as:

```
$ emacs -nw -bg black -fg white
```

too.

Comment: sorry that was a typo!  Updated above.

Comment: This should not have been down-voted.  It was a response based on the OPs typo'd question.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that I had weird colors in terminal mode and finally traced it down to a font face customization. I had something like this:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#000a00" :foreground "#ffffed" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 113 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "Droid Sans Mono")))))
```

I removed the foreground and background properties and everything started looking hunky-dory.